# Go_router path is being redirected the same path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

only screen with path '/' is being redirected. Path other than this is also being redirected to '/'. why?`

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
routes: <RouteBase>[
  GoRoute(
    path: '/',
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      return  SplashScreen();
    },
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: 'moon',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return  CustomBar(indexTab: 4);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
],
```

);

Comment: You need to add a default `route` handler for paths other than '/'.

Comment: Maybe you used context.go('/') to navigate ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return  SplashScreen();
        },
          GoRoute(
            path: '/moon',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return  CustomBar(indexTab: 4);
            },
          ),
      ),
    ],
);
```

try this